# Why does my name not appear while flagging posts?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging

This is a question, not a growl.

So I flagged a question one day and I was happy for flagging that post and moved on. But when I came back, it did have the [closed] symbol, but it did not make my name appear on the thing. etc

**Closed as unclear what you are talking about: Seth, Videonauth, Nathan Osman, muru.**

It should have my name but the server thinks it haves a mind of its own...

What is causing this mayhem?!?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because flagging a post is not the same as casting a vote to close (commonly abbreviated as VTC around here). Everyone with at least 15 reputation can flag a post but only users with 3000 reputation or more can vote to close (see https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/close-questions). The names that appeared in your example were those who voted to close the question.

Comment: That is weird. Upon checking that post I have the same option.